# can't import holoviews, error: ImportError: cannot import name 'Column' from 'bokeh.models' (unknown location)

Tags: sympy, holoviews

When i try to import holoviews i get a error. I have installed it in my prompt with pip install holoviews and

```
jupyter labextension install @pyviz/jupyterlab_pyviz
```

But when i use the command:

```
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')
```

i get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [8], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import holoviews as hv
      2 hv.extension('bokeh')

File ~\calculus\simpy\lib\site-packages\holoviews\__init__.py:85, in <module>
     81 __version__ = str(param.version.Version(fpath=__file__, archive_commit="$Format:%h$",
     82                                         reponame="holoviews"))
     84 from . import util                                       # noqa (API import)
---> 85 from .annotators import annotate                         # noqa (API import)
     86 from .core import archive, config                        # noqa (API import)
     87 from .core.boundingregion import BoundingBox             # noqa (API import)

File ~\calculus\simpy\lib\site-packages\holoviews\annotators.py:8, in <module>
      4 from inspect import getmro
      6 import param
----> 8 from panel.pane import PaneBase
      9 from panel.layout import Row, Tabs
     10 from panel.util import param_name

File ~\calculus\simpy\lib\site-packages\panel\__init__.py:48, in <module>
      1 """
      2 Panel is a high level app and dashboarding framework
      3 ====================================================
   (...)
     46 https://panel.holoviz.org/getting_started/index.html
     47 """
---> 48 from . import layout  # noqa
     49 from . import links  # noqa
     50 from . import pane  # noqa

File ~\calculus\simpy\lib\site-packages\panel\layout\__init__.py:31, in <module>
      1 """
      2 Layout
      3 ======
   (...)
     29 https://panel.holoviz.org/getting_started/index.html
     30 """
---> 31 from .accordion import Accordion  # noqa
     32 from .base import (  # noqa
     33     Column, ListLike, ListPanel, Panel, Row, WidgetBox,
     34 )
     35 from .card import Card  # noqa

File ~\calculus\simpy\lib\site-packages\panel\layout\accordion.py:7, in <module>
      3 from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, ClassVar, Mapping
      5 import param
----> 7 from bokeh.models import Column as BkColumn, CustomJS
      9 from .base import NamedListPanel
     10 from .card import Card

ImportError: cannot import name 'Column' from 'bokeh.models' (unknown location)
```

I dont know how to fix this can anyone help?

The command used to work fine but I reinstalled jupiter notebook because the program wouldn't start. After reinstalling it I can't use holoviews anymore.

Comment: Usually this means bokeh isn't installed in the same environment as you are running, or has the wrong version. Try "import bokeh", and if that fails, install a compatible version of bokeh. If it succeeds, check `bokeh.__version__`; it presumably won't be a version compatible with your installed version of Panel.